# Not Parsing all data - only header of table

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup

Just not fully understanding the datetime import yet as when i parse over to get data i'm not able to get full table data

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate="

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=')

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

format = "%d-%m-%y"
delta = timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

yesterday1 = yesterday.strftime(format)
enddate = datetime(2018, 1, 1)
enddate1 = enddate.strftime(format)
while enddate <= yesterday:
    enddate += timedelta(days=1)
    enddate.strftime(format)
    new_url = base_url + str(enddate)
    soup12 = requests.get(new_url)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(soup12.content, "html.parser")
    table1 = soup1.find('table', class_='meetingListFull')
    for table2 in table1.find('td'):
        name = table2.find('a')
```

i want to re-iterate over all names from datelist to eventually get all href and **scrape** data from all past results. Below is actually what i want to get from table1 data but it was not showing up.

[Globe Derby Park](/racing/fields/race-fields/?mc=GD060420)

So purpose is create href to reiterate over to get all href for past 2 years, re-iterate over tables and then get data from each href below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code for your loop:

```py
for tr in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_cells = tr.find_all('td')
    if all_cells:
        name_cell = all_cells[0]
        try:
            text = name_cell.a.text.strip()
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print(text)
```

`find_all` returns an iterable list and since you only look for a name, just use the first cell.

Hope that helps.

Comment: no, i want to re-iterate over all names from datelist to eventually get al href and scrap data from all past results.
Below is actually what i want to get from table1 data but it was not showing up. 

<a href="/racing/fields/race-fields/?mc=GD060420">Globe Derby Park</a>

So purpose is create href to reiterate over to get all href for past 2 years, re-iterate over tables and then get data from each href below

Comment: Ok. But that was not obvious since your last statement is just `print(name)`. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61244026/edit) your original post and tell us, what you'd expect or what's the goal/purpose. Be more specific.